# How to call a Microsoft office outlook Macro from C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, outlook

I have a Macro which fetches some data into the excel file from the Microsoft office outlook (inbox or any other folder). To get the excel file I have to manually run the Macro in the outlook. Is there any way to call the Macro from the C#. I tried to search on Google but couldn’t find anything specific. This is an **immediate requirement**. Any help with this!!

Answer (score 1):

[Look here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683) This should get you started.

its something along the lines of:

```
myApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass)(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"));
```

then have a `RunMacro(object theApp, object[] theArgs)` method, then you will need to invoke a run on the app and the data inside this method.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please be kind enough and tell me how i have to specify the Macro path in C#. I am clueless.

Comment: `theApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, theApp, theArgs);`
Im guessing something along these lines. Not tested though.

Then run with: `RunMacro(myApp, new Object[] { "macroName" });`